# SwiftUI - Storing Value of Button Selection

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an `HStack` of buttons which a user can select that act like radio buttons. I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the user's selection. I pull `MyRadioButtons()` into another view, and I think my challenge is how to access the `id` associated with each button so that I can then store the ID.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753612/11655223) as a reference and have modified slightly to fit my needs, but this is more or less my code

```
struct MyRadioButton: View {
    let id: Int
    @Binding var currentlySelectedId: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.currentlySelectedId = self.id }, label: { Text("Tap Me!") })
            .foregroundColor(id == currentlySelectedId ? .green : .red)
    }
}


struct MyRadioButtons: View {
    @State var currentlySelectedId: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyRadioButton(id: 1, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 2, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 3, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 4, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the view the user is interacting with, I have this in a `VStack` along with some other fields...

```
     MyRadioButtons()
     Button(action: {
     item.selection = [RadioButton ID Here]})
```

Comment: If you're using macOS, you can use a `Picker` and the `RadioGroupPickerStyle`

Comment: @Sam - Sorry! This is for iOS. The "radio buttons" aren't really a radio button. They're buttons which act like radio buttons such that when one is tapped its appearance shows it's the selected option and the others are deselected.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm writing an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```swift
struct MyRadioButton: View {
    let id: Int
    @Binding var currentlySelectedId: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.currentlySelectedId = self.id }, label: { Text("Tap Me!") })
            .foregroundColor(id == currentlySelectedId ? .green : .red)
    }
}


struct MyRadioButtons: View {
    init(selection: Binding<Int>) {
        self._currentlySelectedId = selection
    }
    @Binding var currentlySelectedId: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyRadioButton(id: 1, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 2, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 3, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
            MyRadioButton(id: 4, currentlySelectedId: $currentlySelectedId)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyRadioButtons(selection: $selection)
            Button(action: {
                //whatever
            }) {
                Text("Click me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it! Just had to call `self.selection` within the button action to store it. Thanks :)